# How to find the cumulative product in a pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this following data of dates and factors as follows. In a pandas dataframe. The ... indicates data in between those dates.
No factor means its blank.

```
Date           Factor  
1 Jan 1990     1       
2 Jan 1990             
...            ...     
5 May 1991     0.5     
6 May 1991             
....           ...     
5 May 1992             
6 May 1992     2       
...            ...     
10 March 1995  0.1    
...            ...     
17 June 1997   3
```

I need to create a new column that does a cumulative product as the time goes by but of all the dates that are available.

So right now there dates in between those dates that i have listed but the columns rows are blank in between the dates.

How do I automate this process within pandas the do the following?

```
Date           Factor  Cumprod
1 Jan 1990     1       1
2 Jan 1990             1
...            ...     ...
5 May 1991     0.5     0.5 (0.5 * 1) 
6 May 1991             0.5
....           ...     0.5
5 May 1992             0.5
6 May 1992     2       1.0 (0.5 * 2 * 1)
...            ...     ..
10 March 1995  0.1     0.1 (0.5 * 2 * 1 * 0.1)
...            ...     ...
17 June 1997   3       0.3 (0.5 * 2 * 1 * 0.1 * 0.3)
```

The cumprod will calculate as a factor appears in the row beside it. And even if there are blanks in the row next to it it should take the cumprod that was calculated above it and use that to fill the empty row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
`df['Cumprod'] = df['Factor'].cumprod()`

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumprod.html