# Calculate running total based off original value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I wish to take an inital value of 1000 and multiply it by the first value in the 'Change' and then take that value and multiply it to the second value in the 'Change' column and so on.

I could do this by using a loop as follows

```
changes = [0.97,1.02,1.1,0.88,1.01 ]
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Change'] = changes

df['Total'] = np.nan
df['Total'][0] = 1000*df['Change'][0]
for i in range(1,len(df)):
    df['Total'][i] = df['Total'][i-1] * df['Change'][i]
```

Output:

```
   Change      Total
0   0.97    970.000000
1   1.02    989.400000
2   1.10    1088.340000
3   0.88    957.739200
4   1.01    967.316592
```

But this will be too slow for a large dataset. Is there any way to do this without loops?

Thanks

Comment: [`pandas.DataFrame.cumprod`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumprod.html)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find the cumulative product in a pandas dataframe column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56741808/how-to-find-the-cumulative-product-in-a-pandas-dataframe-column)

Comment: ``df.assign(Total = df.Change.mask(df.index == 0, df.Change.mul(1000)).cumprod())``